# How to call a custom ruleset.xml for php code sniffer

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer, phpundercontrol

I'm trying to write an custom ruleset.xml for php code sniffer but calling it from the commandline without putting it in the default folder doesn't seem to work.

[Since the documentations seems to state otherwise](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.php.php-codesniffer.annotated-ruleset.php) i'd like to ask if i'm doing something wrong here

```
:~/$ phpcs --standard=/home/edo/custom_ruleset.xml source/
===>
ERROR: the "/home/edo/custom_ruleset.xml" coding standard is not installed.
The installed coding standards are PEAR, PHPCS, Zend, Squiz and MySource
```

If that doesn't work: Any suggestions on how to ship your own coding standard with your source ? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need at least [version 1.3.0a1](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer/download/1.3.0a1) of Code Sniffer to use annotated rulesets:

> - All CodingStandard.php files have been replaced by ruleset.xml files
>     Custom standards will need to be converted over to this new format to continue working
> - You can specify a path to your own custom ruleset.xml file by using the `--standard` command line arg
>     e.g., `phpcs --standard=/path/to/my/ruleset.xml`

Before that, you had to [copy your ruleset, as explained in this tutorial](http://www.kingkludge.net/2009/02/codesniffer-part-3-writing-an-example-codesniffer-standard/).